# Slick MSSQL "Failed to create Slick database config for key default"

Tags: sql-server, scala, playframework, slick

I am having difficulty connecting to our MSSQL database using Slick.

I know that I have to use Slick Extensions and have done so. Here is an excerpt from our build

```
lazy val thirdPartyDependencies = Seq(
    ...
    "com.typesafe.slick"    %% "slick-extensions"             % "3.1.0",
    "com.typesafe.play"     %% "play-slick"                   % "1.1.0",
    "com.typesafe.slick"    %% "slick-codegen"                % "3.1.0" % "compile"
)

lazy val allResolvers = Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
)
```

Here's the application.conf configuration for Slick

```
#Slick configuration.
slick.dbs.default.driver=com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
slick.dbs.default.db.url=${?db.default.url}
slick.dbs.default.db.user=${?sql_user}
slick.dbs.default.db.password=${?sql_password}
```

I built the Table definition using the `SourceCodeGenerator` tool without issues. Here's the code that connects to the database:

```
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
```

I don't have any compile time problems but run into the following stack trace when I run the code:

```
[error] play.api.db.slick.DefaultSlickApi - Failed to create Slick database config for key default.
slick.SlickException: Error getting instance of Slick driver "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver"
       at slick.backend.DatabaseConfig$.forConfig(DatabaseConfig.scala:65) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.0.jar:na]
       at play.api.db.slick.DefaultSlickApi$DatabaseConfigFactory.create(SlickApi.scala:89) [play-slick_2.11-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
       ...
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       at slick.backend.DatabaseConfig$.forConfig(DatabaseConfig.scala:63) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.0.jar:na]
       ... 22 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.<init>()
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I'm completely new to Slick. We have a commercial typesafe license so I figure we should probably be using some of the slick features provided therein. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems like Slick cannot find your MSSQL data driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in your `application.conf` configuration file.  Try putting in a trailing `$` at the end of the driver name to tell Slick to refer to it as an object:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver$"
```

Please read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000823/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-with-play-slick-1-0-1-slick-3-0-configuration) for more information.