# Slick 3.2.x on unsupported database

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Let me refresh already asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927224/how-to-use-a-non-supported-database-in-slick-3-1), as the answer there is not clear for newbie.
  I'm trying to start with Play, Slick 3.2.3 and unsupported database (RDB to be precise). I began from play-scala-isolated-slick-example taken from Play site. RDB database is not supported by Slick, so I tried to use generic Jdbc profile (fit-all as I think):

```
package test.mydb.slick
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import test.mydb.{MyTblDAO, Tbl}  // case class defined there
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

@Singleton
class SlickMyTblDAO @Inject()(db: Database)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) 
    extends MyTblDAO with test.mydb.slick.Tables {

//  override val profile: JdbcProfile = _root_.slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
override val profile: JdbcProfile = slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import profile.api._

def lookup(id: String): Future[Option[MyTbl]] = {....  and so on
```

This code is not compiled because of:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : slick.driver.JdbcProfile.type
[error]  required: slick.driver.JdbcProfile
[error]     (which expands to)  slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
[error]   override val profile: JdbcProfile = slick.driver.JdbcProfile
[error]                                                    ^
```

Not sure I fully understand the root of the problem, but I guess one can't use Jdbc profile directly. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927224/how-to-use-a-non-supported-database-in-slick-3-1) says that "other databases can be supported with a custom implementation of the trait slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile". Does it mean that I need to implement profile myself? Is it achievable for starter? I need just a simple DML, no DDL, no joins for start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `profile` needs to extend the *trait* `JdbcProfile`, but you're passing it the *companion object* `JdbcProfile`, which does not extend the trait of the same name.

To answer your other question - yes, I'm afraid you would have to implement `JdbcProfile` yourself, and I believe that could be quite a mouthful for a newbie, because Slick's API is quite advanced.

Comment: Hmm... Strange enough, but it succeeded. Profile created from existing profiles and wild guesses is far from perfect, of course, but I got first results. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, would you give more explanation or example if possible? do you still use slick 3.X @Valent

Comment: It was definitely not a rocket science. I took Oracle profile, commented out all DDL stuff as it was out of interest and expected to bring a lot of problems, commented out some features which do not exist in RDB and added some features which do. I tried to be as conservative as possible so result was able to proceed simple queries (I did not test complex things, to be honest), but it was sufficient for me at the moment. All of this was done in Slick 3.2.3 source. I can share the result but I guess you don't need namely RDB profile but something else.